# Equation to the circle.

Tags: analytic-geometry, circles

How to show that the equation to the circle of which the points $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$ are the ends of a cord of a segment containing an angle $\theta$ is,
$$(x-x_1)(x-x_2)+(y-y_1)(y-y_2) ± \cot(\theta)[(x-x_1)(y-y_2)-(x-x_2)(y-y_1)]=0$$

Comment: See http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h306012

Comment: Please show me how to proceed.

Comment: You ask how to proceed. I ask you the same thing as @Lovsovs.  If you are completely blocked, I can say how I have found the demonstration: I have spotted a dot product on the left hand side, and, once I looked at the right hand side, I asked myself "It looks like a determinant of the same vectors I have on the left",  I can interpret a determinant as the area of the generated parallelogram, but after a moment, I realized that I had better to do by expressing it at the norm of the cross product which does the same job.

Comment: Another way of  stating the circle property that angle $ \theta$  subtended by triangle's legs at circumference of circle is constant that can be found from dot product of the vectors.Or it may be also product of cutting line segments.

Answer (score 0):

I have had a look at the reference you have  given, @lab bhattacharjee. It is exactly the same problem wording. The solutions given there are interesting. I provide another one which, in my opinion, provides a more direct path.

Let $M_k(x_k,y_k)$. Let $O$ be the center of the circle. Let us assume that angle $(\overrightarrow{OM_1},\overrightarrow{OM_2})=2 \theta$.

Point $M$ belongs to the circle if and only if $(\overrightarrow{MM_1},\overrightarrow{MM_2})=\theta$ (half angle property). This constraint can be interpretated in the following way:

$\dfrac{|\overrightarrow{MM_1}.\overrightarrow{MM_2}|}{\| \overrightarrow{MM_1}\times \overrightarrow{MM_2}\|}$
$=\dfrac{\|\overrightarrow{MM_1}\|\|\overrightarrow{MM_2}\|(\pm\cos{\theta
})}{\|\overrightarrow{MM_1}\|\|\overrightarrow{MM_2}\|\sin{\theta
}}=\pm\dfrac{\cos{\theta}}{\sin{\theta}}=\pm\cot{\theta}$.

It suffice now to turn to the analytical expressions of the dot product and the cross product to obtain the given equation.